# ASP.NET MVC: Populate multiple textboxes with values after the first has an entry

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

So, my view has multiple textboxes, a user inputs a value e.g. a customer number in the first textbox. After that multiple other textboxes e.g. customer name, customer adress should be autofilled with the fitting values of the database record of that customer.

So what did I do to solve my problem? I looked around the web for similar solutions, but could not find one, that solves the problem I got here. I do not expect anyone to write the code here, just hoping for a hint or an example how this could be done, if it can be done the way I think it should work. Thank you!

Comment: Handle the change event of your textbox (which should be a dropdownlist) using javascript, and use ajax to call a server method (passing the value) which returns the details and in the success callback, update the DOM

Comment: Or read up the MVC way to do this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Thanks for your answer @StephenMuecke, I will try to implement that later and will let you know if it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

**Easy way**

After they enter their customer number they click a submit button.

Your page sends a request via a form post to your controller action.

The controller action looks up their information in your database, then populates your view model with these values and redirects back to that page.

**Little bit harder but more common these days**

When they enter their customer number and click submit, intercept the button click with javascript/jQuery.

Create and send an AJAX request to your controller action.

The controller action returns customer data in JSON format.

Once you receive the data back in your AJAX success callback, populate the rest of the form fields using javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to work without a button if thats possible in a way like Stephen Muecke described above, if that does not work, I will try your solution, but I still want to thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure how Stephen's answer is meant to work. You can't really have a dropdown menu for a customer ID field as you would have to populate it with every customer ID in your database, which you obviously wouldn't do. It really has to be a text field. Anyway, let us know how you go and if you need more help.